# Personal GPU running while using remote Desktop

Tags: process, gpu, remote-desktop, amd-gpu

I am connected to a remote desktop so I can train my model by using GPU (10 Go). However, I noticed after some time that my local GPU (AMD Intel on my local desktop) is being used as well for about 35%~40%. I don't know if it is normal as this just started to happen recently. When I ran `nvidia-smi`, the only process going on was `mstsc.exe`.

What do you think is the problem if there is any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mstsc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc) is use for :

> Creates connections to Remote Desktop Session Host servers or other
> remote computers and edits an existing Remote Desktop Connection
> (.rdp) configuration file

So this task is the display of your remote pc on your actual pc.